# Importing Data from CSV without longitude and latitude but a location code

Tags: qgis, csv, attribute-joins

[image]

I am new to QGIS. Above is the image of data I have. The .shp file in QGIS have that geographical department codes as well. I want to read the data from CSV and plot in map but don't know what to put in x-axis and y-axis. Below image have the result I want to get. [image]

Comment: I have a .shp file with department boundaries. You mean I should have the longitude and latitude for plotting them, we can't do it with that first column of data as .shp file have reference of it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Load both files into QGIS. Load your CSV without any geometries. Then perform a join: right click your shapefile-layer with the department boundaries, go to --> properties --> joins. Click "add new join":

[image]

Then choose your CSV and the matching field:

[image]

If you now open the attribute table of your boundary layer, it will contain all data from your CSV. Style them or label them as you wish.

You could also save this boundary layer now to a new file. This new file will permamentely contain this data. Otherwise this data will only be available within your QGIS project.

Comment: Thanks for help, it worked. Data is in the table. Can you please help me how to transform it like the way my output is? I'm really new to all this.